# How to convert ImageBox.Image to Image<Bgr, Byte>

Tags: c#, emgucv

I need to have the image of my (Emgu CV version 3) `ImageBox` in an image variable, how should I do this?

I tried this without luck:

```
 Image<Bgr, Byte> imgeOrigenal;
 imgeOrigenal = ImageBoxbOrigenal.Image; //error line
```

Results in:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Emgu.CV.IImage' to 'Emgu.CV.Image'. An explicit conversion exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it through the source bitmap, like this:

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> imgeOrigenal = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(ImageBoxbOrigenal.Image.Bitmap);
```